# jQuery: scroll left / right to next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent `.slider-wrap` div at `100%` width, with 3 `.slider-slide-wrap` child divs inside, each at `680px` width. You can scroll horizontally inside the `.slider-wrap` div.

I've also created 2 `.slider-nav` divs, `#slider-left` sitting on the left, and `#slider-right` sitting on the right, the idea being, you can scroll as you wish using the scrollbar, but if you clicked the `#slider-right` div at any time, it would slide you across to the next instance of `.slider-slide-wrap` divs. Thus, the 2 `.slider-nav` divs will take you left and right to the next / previous instance of `.slider-slide-wrap` div.

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/rAb3V/

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrap">
    <div class="slide-wrap">
        <div class="slider-slide-wrap"></div>
        <div class="slider-slide-wrap"></div>
        <div class="slider-slide-wrap"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slider-left" class="slider-nav"></div>
<div id="slider-right" class="slider-nav"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var n = $(".slider-slide-wrap").length,
        width = 680,
        newwidth = width * n;

    $('.slide-wrap').css({
        'width': newwidth
    });

});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slider-slide-wrap").each(function (i) {
        var thiswid = 680;
        $(this).css({
            'left': thiswid * i
        });
    });
});
```

If this is at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of I think you need to have an indicator to identify which slide the user has scrolled to, or which slide is currently on the viewport in order for this scroll left & right to work properly.

```
/*on scroll move the indicator 'shown' class to the
most visible slide on viewport
*/
$('.slider-wrap').scroll(function () {
    var scrollLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
    $(".slider-slide-wrap").each(function (i) {
        var posLeft = $(this).position().left
        var w = $(this).width();

        if (scrollLeft >= posLeft && scrollLeft < posLeft + w) {
          $(this).addClass('shown').siblings().removeClass('shown');
        }
    });
});
/* on left button click scroll to 
   the previous sibling of the current visible slide */
$('#slider-left').click(function () {
    var $prev = $('.slide-wrap .shown').prev();
    if ($prev.length) {
        $('.slider-wrap').animate({
            scrollLeft: $prev.position().left
        }, 'slow');
    }
});
/* on right button click scroll to 
   the next sibling of the current visible slide */
$('#slider-right').click(function () {
    var $next = $('.slide-wrap .shown').next();
    if ($next.length) {
        $('.slider-wrap').animate({
            scrollLeft: $next.position().left
        }, 'slow');
    }
});
```

See it working of this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rAb3V/2/).

PS. You also don't need a lot of `$(document).ready()`, one will do just fine and a best practice to do.